# Return a maximum frequency word returned by tabulate

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to count the number of word in a text using matlab (i.e the frequency of each word) .So i am using the code :

```
a=tabulate(Myword);
```

So after executing ,this code returns an array like this :

```
word .......count......percent

Hi..........10........0.12

No..........20........0.42
```

So i want to return the high frequency word .How can i do that?

I used this code :

```
a=sortrows(a,2);
```

But it doesn't work.

I am so beginner in matlab

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabulate returns a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). You can get the row of the high frequency word like this:

```
[~,idx] = max([a{:,2}])
```

What it does is take the second column of the cell array, transform it into a vector (by `[]`) and take the index of the max value, which is the row index of the word on the cell array. Then, you can use `idx` to retrieve that word:

```
a{idx,1}
```